# Network Load Balancing Manager failover

Tags: networking, load-balancing, nlb

I would like to be notified when one of my clusters in Network Load Balancing Manager starts up or fails. [The documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776931%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) seems to infer that there are no advanced scripting, logging, or notification capabilities in NLB and that my only option is to have it write events to a log.txt file. Is that true?

I need to execute some code in response to the start up/failure of a cluster. Is this possible (without a great deal of work) with NLB as it exists today? If not, what other tools (other than MS Application Center) might I consider using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can monitor NLB Heath with with System Center Operations Manager.

Comment: Sure enough, System Center looks like it has a NLB Pack http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15674